# deleting duplicate cookie on domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, dns

i'm trying to delete a cookie entry from a site. the problem is, when the cookie is registered, it registers on both the `www.domainname.com` and `.domainname.com` of the site, so there is two entries. I am trying to delete the cookie using:

```
jQuery.cookie("cookie","",{expires:-5,domain:".domainname.com"});
jQuery.cookie("cookie","",{expires:-5,domain:"www.domainname.com"});
```

to try and catch both. however, one or the other always stays, and will not get deleted/expired. Anyway to force the cookie to expire? I have access to PHP as well.

Comment: Which cookie is not being removed? Are you on is your script running on "www.domainname.com" or some other sub-domain?

Comment: same domain, and it was random everytime. meaning one or the other cookie would stay. and running the javascript in the console also didn't do anything. I got this fixed however. I added a 3rd line to the above command, same thing except i did not specify a domain. That seem to do the trick

Comment: Did you try just flipping the order? Delete the more specified version before the less specified one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to php you can delete cookie with setcookie function: [setcookie php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).
For you is important fifth argument - domain.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but I just had the same problem trying to set the google translate cookie.

This ended up working:

```
jQuery.cookie("cookie", null, { path: "/",domain: ".domainname.com" });
jQuery.cookie("cookie", null, { path: "/" }); //sets domain:"www.domainname.com"
```